# Google Analytics no data

Tags: google-analytics, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using Prestashop, with a google analytics plugin. I use this plugin with multiple sites, but on one of my websites, i have no data. I can't get data on Real-Time Overview either, altough i'm online.

I checked with TagManager and with GA Debug, both showing that my setup is correct. I also checked multiple times for view filters.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: How long ago did you setup your property? It may take up to 24 for your account to begin processing a new property.

Comment: If is new webpage will take little time to see real-time

Comment: The set-up is at least 1 week old.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new analytics property on a new account. It's working now.
This can be clsoed.